# RavenDB Request URL Too Long

Tags: c#, url, request, ravendb

I am getting the request URL too long problem and wondered if anyone had any ideas on how I could improve what I have...

Here, I return a list of property id's

```
var propertiesAlreadySentQuery = Session.Query<Domain.ClientProperty>().Where(x => x.ClientId == clientid);
var propertiesAlreadySent = new int[propertiesAlreadySentQuery.Count()];
var t = 0;
foreach (var i in propertiesAlreadySentQuery)
{
    propertiesAlreadySent[t] = i.PropertyId;
    t++;
}
```

Now, what I want to do is return a list of properties and filter out those properties that have already been sent (hence the naming!)

```
var results = from p in Session.Query<Domain.Property>()
                                          where
                                              (p.Development.Latitude >= minLat && p.Development.Latitude <= maxLat) &&
                                              (p.Development.Longitude >= minLong && p.Development.Longitude <= maxLong)
                                          select p;

var propertiesNotSent = results.Where(x => !x.PropertyId.In<Int32>(propertiesAlreadySent));
```

Problem is, the number of property id's that are returned in propertiesAlreadySent can be quite alot and I get the Request URL Too long.

Any ideas how I can refine this to not experience this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Is your results.Where() IQueryable or IEnumerable?

Comment: I wish I could help, but I've only been using the Raven .NET API. As a work-around, I supposed you could retrieve everything, then filter in memory. I'll be curious to see the answer here...

Answer (score 1):

Matt,
You are limited in the number of items that you can use in an In() element.
I don't understand what you are trying to do, can you explain the intent behind your code?

Comment: Ok, let me try to explain - I have a list of property details that has already been sent - I want to exclude those from the new property details that people have not already have sent.  Problem is, there is 3000+ documents and although I am filtering by one of the fields it can return alot of properties already sent.  Does that make sense?  I have thought of a work around - just testing now to see if it works..

Comment: Looks like limiting the dataset on another collection has done the trick.  Huge fan of RavenDB and like the way it essentially makes you write better code.  Pain in the backside too when your boss is on your back saying "Is it finished yet"....